# How to use terminal arguments with values in Java?

Tags: java, terminal, arguments

For my school project I am creating a game like Bad Apples for iPhone (not my personal choice but it isn't the problem).

The game needs to have two versions, the first one in console and the second one in JavaFX. But I wanted to go a little further with that.  I want to add arguments that the user can add to the terminal when launching the game, for example

> java -jar BadApplesClone.jar --height=10 --width=10 --numPieces=5

And then I will handle all the values introduced and change the variables.

I am using OpenJDK6, and so I am doing like this for now :

```
    for (int i=0; i<args.length; i++)
    {
        if (args[i].equals("--help"))
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");

        if (args[i].equals("--largura"))
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");

        if (args[i].equals("--altura"))
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");

        if (args[i].equals("--pecas_inicio"))
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");

        if (args[i].equals("--javafx"))
        {
            JavaFX javaFX = new JavaFX(ALTURA, LARGURA, PECAS_INICIO);
            javaFX.initJogo();
        }
    }
```

But I don't know how to handle the values like --width=10.. I have thought of an enum, but I don't really know how to do that.

Can anyone explain me a way to achieve this?

Comment: `have thought of an Enum class but i don't really know how to do that` What have you tried?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200054/java-library-for-parsing-command-line-parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the question you actually asked ...

Some of the elements of your args array are of the form "--SOMETHING=ANOTHER".

So, first thing you need is:

```
if(args[x].startsWith("--SOMETHING")) {
```

The second problem is to parse off the ANOTHER.

```
args[x].split("=")
```

is the place to start with that.

Answer (score 2):

If you are allowed to use external libraries, check out [Apache Commons CLI](http://commons.apache.org/cli/), which will save you from re-inventing a wheel.

Comment: I don't think I can use external libraries :S... I will see what it is anyways ^^ Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you are using JavaFX you can use the `getParameters` method in the Application class (please note, *not* in the constructor though), it handles **both** parameters from the command line as well from the jnlp file!

> public final Application.Parameters getParameters()
>
> Retrieves the parameters for this Application, including any arguments
>   passed on the command line and any parameters specified in a JNLP file
>   for an applet or WebStart application. NOTE: this method should not be
>   called from the Application constructor, as it will return null. It
>   may be called in the init() method or any time after that.

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/application/Application.html#getParameters()

For further details see the documentation for the returned object:
http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/application/Application.Parameters.html

It handles both named and unnamed (and can always get the raw parameters of course).

> **Named parameters** you get as a `Map` from calling `getNamed()` and include those  pairs explicitly specified in a JNLP file. It also includes any command line arguments of the form: "--name=value"
>
> **Unnamed parameters** you get as a `List` by calling `getUnnamed()` Are the simple ones you already handle today in your code, meaning, that the named parameters, that is the parameters that are represented as  pairs, are filtered out from this `List`.

Comment: I've not mentioned that (and I'm really sorry about that :S) but the project must be in 2 fases, the 1º fase is only terminal, and the second one is the JavaFX version, but I wanted to do the 2 right now. So is there anyway to do that without using a javaFX especific parameter ? :S (I will save that for the second fase thought ^^)

Answer (score 1):

There is an interesting discussion of JavaFX and command line parameters in this blog post:
[Exploring JavaFX 2 - Accessing application parameters](http://nagaimasato.blogspot.com/2012/05/javafx-and-application-parameters.html), in which the author recommends that you "let [Application.getParameters()](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/application/Application.html#getParameters%28%29) to act a transporter and ask Apache Commons CLI to take the main work" by which he means just get the raw parameter data rather than the parsed parameters:

```
getParameters().getRaw().toArray(new String[getParameters().getRaw().size()])
```

This translates the parameters to a JavaFX example into the same kind of String array you get from a command line app, and you can then handle the parameter parsing using a common function.

If you can't use [Apache Commons CLI](http://commons.apache.org/cli/) in your project, you could implement a basic parameter parser for your app yourself which handles in a common function the parsing based upon the parameters retrieved from a `getParameters().getRaw().toArray` call (in JavaFX mode) or the `main()` args passed to your app (in command line mode).