# Passing -d option in java

Tags: java

I am solving a question where the requirement is that the program should allow the user to set a parameter with the -d command-line option.  Does java provide any mechanism to pass argument with -d option? I couldn't find any so I am interpreting this as if the command line option value is -d, that means that user wants to enter the parameter next.

```
if ( args[0].equals("-d") )
{
     parameter = args[0];
}
```

Is this right way to check that? Is there some better way to check whether user has entered `-d` option? Does java provides some other mechanism for that?

Comment: Use a command line argument parser. [JCommander](http://jcommander.org/) (no affiliation) is my preference - there are others.

Comment: Then `parameter = "-d"`, or `null` - is that what you want? Have a look at Apache Commons CLI for example; and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10745811/how-to-use-terminal-arguments-with-values-in-java

Answer (score 2):

I think the requirement means `-D` (the capital one), not `-d`. Such options are used to pass additional parameters to java. For instance, `-Dmy.option=value`. In such case you have access to this property by means of `System` class:

```
String myOption = System.getProperty("my.option");
```

Answer (score 1):

What if someone runs the program with `./yourapp something else -d`?
Now the argument -d exists, but not on position 0

So, my recommendation is to loop through all of the arguments and check what you need.

```
int i;
boolean dParam = false;
for (i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
    if (args[i].equals("-d")) {
        dParam = true;
    }
}
```

If you want the user to input something after the -d, like a filename then I would recommend doing this:

```
int i;
boolean dParam = false;
String dParamValue;

for (i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
    if (args[i].equals("-d")) {
        dParam = true;
        dParamValue = args[++i];
    }
}
```

Comment: This is beginning to look at lot like reinventing a wheel. Yours is somewhat square at best...

Comment: It's not reinventing the wheel. It's an updated version of OP's initial code that works.

Answer (score 0):

All parameters you pass to the program you are running, are going in the application throug the parameter  **String[] args** in the main method..

You can then check if the dictionary is there requested, by just checking if the array of arguments contains that key..

## Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
System.out.println("is dictionary there?: " + Arrays.asList(args).contains("d"));

if (Arrays.asList(args).contains("d")) {
    prepateDictionary();
}else {
    prepareSomethingElse();
}

}
```